# Determine when a point has passed a point on a line using a line perpendicular

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to figure out if $a_{4}$, which is an object moving in the direction shown, has passed the perpendicular line at point $a_{2}$ along the line $a_{1}$ to $a_{3}$.

I also want to be able to determine the same regardless of the direction of the line. NW to SE, E to W etc etc

[image]

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Could you please edit the question to be more specific about what constitutes "passing the point along the line"? As it stands, this is unclear and we therefore cannot provide an answer and the question may be closed. Do you mean, for instance, when the moving point $a_4=(x_4,y_4)$ crosses the perpendicular to the line at $a_2$?

Comment: If you *do* mean to ask when $a_4$ crosses the perpendicular to the line at $a_2$, then it should be straightforward to find the perpendicular, relating the slopes with $m_1\cdot m_2 = -1$ and solving $y=mx+c$ for the intercept $c$ with a given point, and then solve for when the position formula for $a_4$ coincides with that perpendicular.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! @Jam I edited to question to hopefully be clearer. Yes I want to determine if $a_{4}$ has passed the perpendicular to the line at $a_{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the normal vector of the line, take the inner product of the normal and the vector from any point on the line to the point.

If this inner product is 0 (or crosses zero), the point is on the line or crosses the line

Comment: Conveniently in this case, the vector from $a_1$ to $a_2$ is orthogonal to the dotted line and can be used as the normal vector. (You can normalize it to unit length but don't really have to for this purpose.) Also, $a_2$ is a "point on the line".